# Floating action button and full screen white background

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using following FAB library
https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button. 
and following this stackoverflow post [Floating action button and white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992058/floating-action-button-and-white-background/27992149) to show overlay over screen.

I am using FloatingActionButton in Fragment using above mentioned post, but overlay does not come over action bar. 
Not able to find any solution to display overlay over full screen(including action bar)

Code
Fragment.java

```
final FrameLayout fl =    FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.floatingcontainer);        
final FloatingActionsMenu fam = (FloatingActionsMenu) fl.findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);       

fam.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0ffffff"));               

        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);               
        }
    });


    fl.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // ignore all touch events
            if(fam.isExpanded()){
                fam.collapse();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourapp.data"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp">

//some previous code

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:id="@+id/floatingcontainer"   
    android:clickable="false" >

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="66dp"        
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/orange"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/orange_pressed"           
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style" >

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/menu1"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/orange"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/orange_pressed"
            fab:fab_title="Menu 1" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/menu2"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/orange"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/orange_pressed"
            fab:fab_title="Menu 2" />


    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, 
Pawan

Comment: Please add the code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code, but I assume that you use a ActionbarActivity. The Actionbar used there does not belong to yout layout and therefore the FrameLayout does not draw on top of it.

Follow this Article to create a layout in which you have controll over the ActionBar (using Toolbar): http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

If that's not the Problem you could try to call View.bringToFront() on your Layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the toolbar in your layout and have `FrameLayout` as the parent. Then you can have a view with a transparent background in the layout that you can show and hide in the `OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener` interface methods.