# I need to overlay layout on floating action menu button

Tags: android

I need to overlay layout on floating action menu button click like below example:

https://media.giphy.com/media/CxCkzncaSIXII/giphy.gif

Comment: You have research that, in this site, we will help you to solved the issue in the code, anyway I will share a link of available floating menus select as your requirement https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=Floating

Comment: You can create your own custom view for that. I have also done that in my project but the only different is that the menu items open in a arc manner from the FAB.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari can you provide me code. It will be helpful for me. thanks. :)

Comment: Posted the code as answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

[>FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

or

[>android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

For the overlay you must wrap the FAB onto a frameLayout that matches parent width and height then change its color.

Have fun..

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using this library for floating action menu but I need black overlay on fab click. In GIF you can see black layer on fab click.

Comment: I think you should try to wrap your fab onto a FrameLayout that matches width and height of the parent like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992058/floating-action-button-and-white-background

Answer (score 2):

MaterialArcMenu.java

```
public class MaterialArcMenu extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener,MaterialArcMenuItem.OnClickArcMenuItemListener {

    private float mRadius;

    private FloatingActionButton mHintButton;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
    private FrameLayout transparentFrame;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    private Context context;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

    float translateX,translateY;
    private float scaleRatio;


    public MaterialArcMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            init(context);
        }
    }

    public MaterialArcMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcLayout, 0, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            init(context);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void init(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        scaleRatio = 1.0f;
        mRadius = getExactDp(R.dimen.d80dp);
        transparentFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        transparentFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
        transparentFrame.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
        transparentFrame.setAlpha(0.0f);
        this.addView(transparentFrame, 0);

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d80dp));
        mHintButton = new FloatingActionButton(context);
        mHintButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);
        mHintButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)));
        mHintButton.setScaleX(0.8f * scaleRatio);
        mHintButton.setScaleY(0.8f * scaleRatio);
        mHintButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(mHintButton);
        mHintButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        isExpanded = false;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius){
        this.mRadius = radius;
    }

    public void addItem(MaterialArcMenuItem menuItem){
        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d80dp));
        menuItem.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(menuItem);
        menuItem.setAlpha(0.0f);
        menuItem.setOnClickArcMenuItemListener(this);
        mHintButton.bringToFront();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mCurrentAnimator == null) {
            startHintButtonAnimation(v);
            if (!isExpanded) {
                startOpeningAnimation();
            } else {
                startClosingAnimation();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startOpeningAnimation(){
        isExpanded = true;
        transparentFrame.setAlpha(0.2f);
        ArrayList<ObjectAnimator> arrayListObjectAnimators = new ArrayList<ObjectAnimator>(); //ArrayList of ObjectAnimators
        int itemCount = getChildCount()-2;
        float radius = convertDpToPixel(mRadius);
        float angle = 180.0f;
        float paddingAngle = 180.0f /(itemCount-1);
        angle = angle -paddingAngle;
        long delay = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<itemCount+1;i++){
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            angle = (angle+paddingAngle);
            translateX = (float) (0.0f + radius * Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));
            translateY = (float) (0.0f + radius * Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));

            float tranX = (float) (0.0f + (radius+20.0f) * Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));
            float tranY = (float) (0.0f + (radius+20.0f) * Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));

            PropertyValuesHolder alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 0.0f, 1f);
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, alpha);
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(alphaAnimator);

            PropertyValuesHolder transX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, tranX);
            PropertyValuesHolder transY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0, tranY);
            PropertyValuesHolder rotate = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 180, 360);

            ObjectAnimator translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, transX, transY, rotate);
            translateAnimator.setDuration(200);
            translateAnimator.setStartDelay(delay);
            translateAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(translateAnimator);

            PropertyValuesHolder aftertransX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, tranX, translateX);
            PropertyValuesHolder aftertransY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, tranY, translateY);
            ObjectAnimator aftertranslateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, aftertransX, aftertransY);
            aftertranslateAnimator.setDuration(100);
            aftertranslateAnimator.setStartDelay(200 + delay);
            aftertranslateAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(aftertranslateAnimator);

            delay = delay + 50;
            view.setTag(new Point(translateX, translateY));
        }
        ObjectAnimator[] objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.toArray(new ObjectAnimator[arrayListObjectAnimators.size()]);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimators);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        mCurrentAnimator = animatorSet;
        animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
        transparentFrame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrentAnimator == null) {
                    startClosingAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startClosingAnimation(){
        isExpanded = false;
        ArrayList<ObjectAnimator> arrayListObjectAnimators = new ArrayList<ObjectAnimator>(); //ArrayList of ObjectAnimators
        int itemCount = getChildCount()-2;
        long delay = 0;
        for(int i=itemCount;i>=1;i--){
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            Point point = (Point) view.getTag();

            PropertyValuesHolder rotate = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0, 180);
            ObjectAnimator rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view,rotate);
            rotateAnimator.setDuration(100); // 1 second
            //rotateAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            rotateAnimator.setStartDelay(delay);
            rotateAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(rotateAnimator);

            PropertyValuesHolder transX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, point.getTranslateX(), 0);
            PropertyValuesHolder transY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, point.getTranslateY(), 0);
            ObjectAnimator translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, transX, transY);
            translateAnimator.setDuration(200); // 1 second
            translateAnimator.setStartDelay(100 + delay);
            translateAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(translateAnimator);

            PropertyValuesHolder alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1f, 0.0f);
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, alpha);
            alphaAnimator.setStartDelay(300 + delay); // 1 second
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(alphaAnimator);

            delay = delay + 50;
        }
        ObjectAnimator[] objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.toArray(new ObjectAnimator[arrayListObjectAnimators.size()]);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimators);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mCurrentAnimator = animatorSet;
        animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                transparentFrame.setAlpha(0.0f);
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
        transparentFrame.setOnClickListener(null);
        transparentFrame.setClickable(false);
    }

    private void startHidingAnimation() {
        isExpanded = false;
        ArrayList<ObjectAnimator> arrayListObjectAnimators = new ArrayList<ObjectAnimator>(); //ArrayList of ObjectAnimators
        int itemCount = getChildCount() - 2;
        for (int i = itemCount; i >= 1; i--) {
            View view = getChildAt(i);
            Point point = (Point) view.getTag();
            PropertyValuesHolder alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1f, 0.0f);
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, alpha);
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(alphaAnimator);

            PropertyValuesHolder transX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, point.getTranslateX(), 0);
            PropertyValuesHolder transY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, point.getTranslateY(), 0);
            ObjectAnimator translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, transX, transY);
            arrayListObjectAnimators.add(translateAnimator);
        }
        ObjectAnimator[] objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.toArray(new ObjectAnimator[arrayListObjectAnimators.size()]);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimators);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        mCurrentAnimator = animatorSet;
        animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                transparentFrame.setAlpha(0.0f);
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
        transparentFrame.setOnClickListener(null);
        transparentFrame.setClickable(false);
    }

    private void startHintButtonAnimation(View view){
        view.clearAnimation();
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0,360, view.getPivotX(),view.getPivotY());
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(200);
        view.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        rotateAnimation.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickArcMenuItem() {
        startHidingAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isArcMenuAnimating() {
        return mCurrentAnimator != null;
    }

    class Point{
        private float translateX;
        private float translateY;

        public Point(float translateX,float translateY){
            this.translateX = translateX;
            this.translateY = translateY;
        }

        public float getTranslateX(){
            return translateX;
        }

        public float getTranslateY(){
            return translateY;
        }
    }

public float getExactDp(int dimensionResource) {
        return getContext().getResources().getDimension(dimensionResource) / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

public float convertDpToPixel(float dp){
        Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
        return px;
    }
}
```

MaterialArcMenuItem.java

```
public class MaterialArcMenuItem extends FloatingActionButton {

    private OnClickArcMenuItemListener onClickArcMenuItemListener;
    private float scaleRatio;

    public MaterialArcMenuItem(Context context, int imageResource) {
        super(context);
        init(imageResource, context);
    }

    public MaterialArcMenuItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int imageResource) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(imageResource, context);
    }

    public MaterialArcMenuItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,int imageResource) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(imageResource, context);
    }

    private void init(int imageResource, Context context) {
        setImageResource(imageResource);
        scaleRatio = 1.0f;
        setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)));
        setScaleX(0.8f * scaleRatio);
        setScaleY(0.8f * scaleRatio);
    }

    public void setOnClickArcMenuItemListener(OnClickArcMenuItemListener onClickArcMenuItemListener){
        this.onClickArcMenuItemListener = onClickArcMenuItemListener;
    }

    public void setArcMenuItemOnClickListener(final OnClickListener listener){
        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!onClickArcMenuItemListener.isArcMenuAnimating()) {
                    startArcMenuItemAnimation(v, listener);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startArcMenuItemAnimation(final View view, final OnClickListener listener){
        PropertyValuesHolder transX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 0.8f * scaleRatio, 1.5f * scaleRatio);
        PropertyValuesHolder transY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 0.8f * scaleRatio, 1.5f * scaleRatio);
        PropertyValuesHolder rotate = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 360, 0);
        ObjectAnimator expandAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, transX, transY);
        ObjectAnimator rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view,rotate);
        //rotateAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setDuration(200);
        animatorSet.playTogether(rotateAnimator, expandAnimator);
        animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                view.setScaleX(0.8f * scaleRatio);
                view.setScaleY(0.8f * scaleRatio);
                listener.onClick(view);
                onClickArcMenuItemListener.onClickArcMenuItem();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    public interface OnClickArcMenuItemListener{
        public void onClickArcMenuItem();

        public boolean isArcMenuAnimating();
    }
}
```

Adding items & handling clicks:

```
MaterialArcMenuItem materialArcMenuItem = new MaterialArcMenuItem(this, R.drawable.your_icon);
        arcMenu.addItem(materialArcMenuItem);
        materialArcMenuItem.setArcMenuItemOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {}
        });
```

Comment: Not perfect but I have managed mentioned effect with ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal.